# What do these abbreviated book descriptions mean?

Tags: translation, abbreviation

I have come across these in various online book catalogues, for example [here](https://www.berliner-auktionshaus.com/auctions/freiverkauf-letzte-auktion/table-of-contents/?showItems&auction_id=112&kls=293&kle=947&kb=&hk=13):

- *Gln.*
- *Ln.*

I am assuming these describe the binding, but I can't work out which is which.

Then there is *Kart.*, which I assume means *Karton*, i.e. boxed, but there is also *kart.*, and I can't tell what that means.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Would you please consider integrating more context into your question? I don't think "online book catalogue" is enough context. I think like the entire passage `8 TITEL, dabei Georg Kolbe; Jakob Wilhelm Fehrle; Wilhelm Lehmbruck; Das Buch vom großen Treck; Finnische Kunst etc., Stuttgart u.a. 1922-1949, ges. ca. 960 S., zahlr. Abb., Ln./HLn., tls. berieben u. fleckig, 1xSU, dieser beschädigt <1105158F ` could fit.

Comment: For antiquarian books there exist [a whole host of abbreviations and special terminology](https://www.zvab.com/buecher-sammeln/abkuerzungsverzeichnis.shtml). And typically it's very specific about the book conditions and - unlike _some_ used book traders - doesn't embellish the state of the book. I've never encountered GLn (not consciously anyway), but of course with HLn in mind, GLn makes sense immediately. Other sources: [here](https://www.code-knacker.de/antiquariat.htm), [here](https://www.buecher-wiki.de/index.php/BuecherWiki/AntiquarischeAbkuerzungen) ... `antiquarische Abkürzungen` ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The page you are linking to has a [list of abbreviations](https://www.berliner-auktionshaus.com/service/abkuerzungsverzeichnis/) (Abkürzungsverzeichnis) in which some abbreviations are explained, e.g.

> Ln. - Leinen (linen)
>
> Hln. - Halbleinen (semi-linen*)
>
> SU - Schutzumschlag (dust jacket)
>
> kart. - kartoniert (bound in boards*)

Another (extended) list of abbreviations can be found [here](https://www.zvab.com/buecher-sammeln/abkuerzungsverzeichnis.shtml).

Unfortunately none of these lists says anything about Gln. . But lucky for us [this page](https://www.zvab.com/K%C3%BCnstlerbriefe-Kunst-Bekenntnisse-Malern-Architekten-Bildhauern/16930892937/bd) says

> rotes Ganzleinen / Leinen / GLn / Ln kl. 8vo im Format 10 x 18 cm

Therefore we can assume Gln. stands for

> Gln. - Ganzleinen (full cloth/pure linen*)

---

- I am not 100% sure that these are the correct English terms. dicct.cc translates "kartoniert" as paperback (Taschenbuch/Softcover), but usually [kartoniert](http://www.mind-the-book.de/gebunden-kartoniert-broschiert-taschenbuch-was-sind-die-unterschiede.html) is used when talking about books with a "hard cover".